# SQL Server + Conditional join

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way which I can perform a conditional join something like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE #Entity 
   (    
    [AutoID] [int],
    [Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
   )

    INSERT #Entity
    EXEC Entity_GetEntitiesByUserId @UserID

    DECLARE @Condition bit = 0

    SELECT * FROM [Stuff] s

       IF @Condition = 1 BEGIN

       INNER JOIN 
       (
        SELECT Code as eCode from
        #Entity
       ) e
        ON E.eCode  = s.EntityCode 

       END

       WHERE DeletedBy IS NULL
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will do logically what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Stuff] s
WHERE 
 DeletedBy IS NULL 
 and (@Condition = 0 or s.EntityCode in (select E.code from #Entitye))
```

Comment: I don't think this is the intention. When `@Condition = 1` the result should contain columns from the `#Entity` table, shouldn't it? I think you've assumed the OP's code reads, `SELECT s.* FROM [Stuff] s...`

Comment: @onedaywhen since OP selects only e.ecode from the second table which is a duplicate of s.entitycode, i think it was a fair assumption..

Comment: just now I observed that condition should be `condition = 0 or ...`

Comment: Thanks, the inner join wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I have a different/simpler solution that works well for me.

Only join on TableC if you supply the param @tableCid

```
        declare @tableCid int = null;
        Select a.Id, b.AId, -- whatever other columns
        from TableA a
        inner join TableB b on b.AId = a.Id 
        left join TableC c on c.Id = b.CId 
    where
        1= case 
            when @tableCid is not null and c.Id = @tableCid then 1 
            when @tableCid is null then 1
        end
```